# Why do we 'return' a member to parliament?

Tags: etymology

OED sense 12b, of the verb *to return* deals with the matter of *returning* a member, at one time by the sheriff, nowadays by a *returning officer*.

It is is part of the wider paragraph 12 meaning headed *Chiefly Law*. Sense 12a deals with the idea of return, in the way of answering an official request for information, such as in:

> 1927   Times 19 Mar. 7/5   The total area of land in use for
>   agricultural purposes was returned at 31,000,000 acres.
>
> 1976   Eastern Evening News (Norwich)  22 Dec. 1/3   Fisher sighed
>   when the not guilty verdicts were returned.
>
> 2006   J. E. Moore Murder on Maryland's Eastern Shore iv. 41   The
>   sheriff returned the writ marked simply, ‘Cepi’ (meaning, ‘I have
>   taken’).

**No information is given on the etymology of this meaning of the verb *return*. So why do we *return* a member to parliament, and why do juries *return* verdicts?**

Comment: We are trying to get him (or her) out of our neighborhoods and back to London? Like returning a defective product?

Comment: You *return* an answer to a question or (in the US) you send the IRS your tax *return* (which is not the tax but the documentation of your liability): you "send something back" in response to a demand (jlike the sheriff in your final example). Tenants in chief responded historically (and for all I know presently, too) to a personal summons, counties and boroughs to writs issued by their sheriffs demanding they designate one of their members to attend; and juries respond to a charge by the magistrate. See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt108murruoft#page/590/mode/2up), 16

Comment: The various usages in your examples are not fully equivalent: An MP is **sent (away)** to Parliament; (1927) The area of land was **reported as being** X acres; (1976) The 'not guilty' verdicts were **pronounced**; (2006) The sheriff **gave or sent back** the writ. The application of *returned* to all these cases is slightly different: in particular, the case of MPs being returned to Parliament seems to have little in common with the 'reporting of information' sense that the other cases exemplify.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes we also make a *tax return* (and heaven help us if we don't). And yes we do all the other things you mention. But when I once used 'returning a member' with an American, I discovered that you do not *return* Members to Congress. So what do you do with them?

Comment: @ErikKowal I wasn't suggesting that other expressions were not used too. The availability of various forms of vocabulary is one of the great joys of English. But there is no question that the MP *sent away* to Parliament in 1927, was also *returned* to Parliament, and the person *returning* him/her would have been the *returning officer* for his constituency, as it would be the case today.

Comment: I think the returning officer returns the election results - the count of votes for each candidate and the name of the winner - not the winner himself, who is returned by the constituency.

Comment: @StoneyB How interesting! I had always assumed that the *Returning Officer* was so called because he *returned* the Member to Parliament. But the OED has an entry for both RO and *returning board*, the US equivalent Both would seem to be named for the reports they make of the voting. But I was also interested to note that *returning boards* in the US are politically controlled by one party or the other, whilst a British RO is a Civil Servant. It epitomises, in quintessence, the different notions of public service in the two countries.

Comment: @StoneyB I think I am beginning to see why a member gets *returned*. It is to do with the voting returns, not the fact (as I thought) that he is *returned* to Westminster.

Comment: In the US, if a legislator is in office, and he comes up for election, and wins, we call this being "re-elected" We would use "return to office" only if a person had previously been in that position, then someone else won it, then the first person won it back.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock No that is a different sense of *return*. We talk about a person being *returned to parliament for the first time*. But, interestingly, we don't seem to use it for other elected bodies such as councils. You don't get *returned* to the Hammersmith Borough Council. I wonder why not?

Comment: Yes, that is a different sense; I only meant to say how we use "return" in American politics, as I have never been to the British Isles. I suppose that my comment was not germane.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Far more germane than many comments made on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the comments were 'on track' in suggesting that the *'return'* was essentially a response to a question or instruction to produce and/or deliver something.  In the case of a jury, it is the Judge's direction to the jury to *'return a verdict'*.

In the case of an election, Parliament issues a *'Writ of Election'* for each separate electorate, instructing the *'Returning Officer'* to conduct the election in that place, and **return** the name of the successful candidate.  So while we say the successful candidate is *'returned'*, essentially it is the name of the successful candidate that is *'returned'* in response to the *'Writ of Election'*, back to Parliament which issued the *'Writ'* in the first place.

The process in Canada is described in their Parliament Website (http://www.parl.gc.ca/marleaumontpetit/DocumentViewer.aspx?Lang=E&Sec=Ch04&Seq=5):

> A writ is a formal written order instructing the returning officer in each electoral district to hold an election to elect a Member of Parliament. The writ specifies the day by which the names of candidates must be entered into nomination, and sets a polling date and a date on which the writ, with the name of the successful candidate noted on the back, is to be returned to the Chief Electoral Officer. (See Figure 4.3.) The returning officer is responsible for the conduct of an election within an electoral district. One returning officer is appointed by the Governor in Council for each electoral district. The returning officer receives instructions from the Chief Electoral Officer and holds office as long as he or she meets the requirements of residency within the electoral district, competency and non-partisanship, or until the electoral boundaries for the riding are changed.

An actual Canadian model *'Writ of Election'* is depicted here:

[image]

The key part of the writ is the text, "And you do cause the name of such member so elected....to be certified to Our Chief Officer, as by law directed as soon as possible...."  This is equivalent to saying the name must be 'returned' to the Chief Officer.

Wikipedia comments on the situation in the United States:

> In the United States, this writ is issued mainly by state governors for filling vacancies in the United States House of Representatives, the United States Senate, or the states' own legislatures

*'Writs'* are less common in US law than British law, but essentially a *'writ'* is not dissimilar to a lawsuit, injunction or subpoena.